# Draw Venn diagrams to describe sets: A ∩ B = ∅, A ⊆ C,C ∩ B = ∅

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Draw Venn diagrams to describe sets A, B, and C that
satisfy the given conditions:

> A ∩ B = ∅, A ⊆ C, C ∩ B = ∅

I have tried to draw the Venn diagram for the specified conditions:
[image]

But, I think the Venn Diagram I have drawn is not the correct one.

Comment: It is not, if fails the very first statement $A \cap B = \emptyset $

Comment: Hint: your Venn diagram will not consist of three mutually overlapping circles!

Comment: Obviously it **isn't** a Venn diagram for **any** of the specified conditions. The question asks for diagrams, plural. You can draw three different diagrams, one for each condition, each with only two sets... *or* you can draw one Venn diagram that satisfies all the conditions (they *are* mutually consistent).

Comment: Can u show how to draw it? I am really unsure.

Comment: No. How would you draw one circle inside another? How would you draw two circles that don't overlap at all?

Answer (score 1):

We don't always have to draw three mutually intersecting circles. Indeed, the given statements translate to mean:

- $A$ and $B$ do not overlap.
- $A$ is completely contained inside $C$.
- $B$ and $C$ do not overlap.